# Angular 2: run a function when user clicked inside an editable field

Tags: angular, focus, directive, blur

I've created a directive for contenteditable fields.
I would like to run a function when the user clicks in an editable field it the field is onfocus and than run other function once the user clicks out of the field meaning the it is out of focus.

I am not clear between the difference of blur vs focus.
(blur) only works for me once the user clicks out of the contenteditable field. If I enable (blur) and (focus) they conflick and (blur) does not work.

any suggestions?

```
import {
    Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges} from "@angular/core";


@Directive({
    selector: '[contenteditableModel]',
    host: {
      '(blur)': 'onEdit()',
       // '(focus)': 'onFocus()'
        //,
       // '(keyup)': 'onEdit()'
    }
})

export class ContentEditableDirective implements OnChanges {
    @Input('contenteditableModel') model: any;
    @Output('contenteditableModelChange') update = new EventEmitter();


    constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef
    ) {}


     onFocus(){
       // run when user clicked in the editable field.
    }


    ngOnChanges(changes) {
        console.log('ContentEditableDirective.ngOnChanges', changes);
       // console.log(changes);
       if (changes.model.isFirstChange())  this.refreshView();
    }

    onEdit() {
        // run an update when user clicked outside the editable field and it is not on focus.
        this.update.emit(value)
    }

    private refreshView() {
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.model
    }



}
```

App.ts

HTML

```
<div  class="line-breaker"
    contenteditable='true'
(contenteditableModelChange)="updatedinnerHtml($event)"
[contenteditableModel]="paragraphText"
></div>
```

TS

```
constructor(){


        this.paragraphText  = 'dddddd';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should solve the problem:

```
import {
    Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges} from "@angular/core";


@Directive({
    selector: '[contenteditableModel]'      
})

export class ContentEditableDirective implements OnChanges {
    @Input('contenteditableModel') model: any;
    @Output('contenteditableModelChange') update = new EventEmitter();


    constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef
    ) {}


@HostListener('focus', ['$event'])
onFocus(e) {
  // run when user clicked in the editable field / is focus.
}

   @HostListener('blur', ['$event'])
    onBlur(e) {
      // run when user clicked outside the field.
    }


    ngOnChanges(changes) {
        console.log('ContentEditableDirective.ngOnChanges', changes);
       // console.log(changes);
       if (changes.model.isFirstChange())  this.refreshView();
    }

    onEdit() {
        // run an update when user clicked outside the editable field and it is not on focus.
        this.update.emit(value)
    }

    private refreshView() {
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.model
    }



}
```

Comment: what's the difference in @HostListener and using host: ?? I thought it is the same thing

Comment: maybe, i'm not using it.
we have a big project which contains only HostListener in our directives.
can you try it ?

Comment: onclick the focus activates my contenteditable is disabled.